# Launch gnome-terminal into GUI via TTY

Tags: unity, gnome, gnome-terminal, gui, tty

My GUI is completely messed up and I need to get the gnome terminal working. Ctrl-Alt-T doesn't work because Unity or Gnome are broken. All I'm getting is a mouse and another program that I launched with other keys. I need to login into TTY (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and write a command that will open the gnome terminal in the GUI (Ctrl+Alt+F7). I already tried nohup and some other command I don't remember. I have also tried placing the terminal into startup but it didn't start at boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From tty1 you can open the gnome-terminal in tty7 (where the GUI should be started) by running the following command:

```
env DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal
```

See some more explanations in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1584411/2353900).

Comment: Thanks, ok its good. If i have a question about restoring gnome, can i ask you if anything?

Comment: @NickBailuc Then try to reinstall [ubuntu-desktop](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-desktop/) package (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`) if this is what you use as GUI...

Comment: Ive done that, i reinstalled gnome, unity, xorg, ubuntudesktop. This was initially a driver issue.